# Is it possible to undo an SVN commit WITHOUT changing my working copy?

Tags: svn

I've accidentally checked-in a file to SVN.

I'd like to undo this.

I know I can `svn merge -r COMMITTED:PREV`. and then check-in my working copy.

But now I've lost the work I've done locally.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out another working copy & perform your reverse merge there. Or copy your changes elsewhere, perform the merge, then copy your changes back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have modified Working Copy, you can (except noted recipes)

- Commit changes and reverse-merge later, in clean WC
- Discover branching and merging: save you modified WC as new branch, reverse-merge trunk, merge branch to trunk
- Save changes into patch (`svn diff`), restore pristine WC (`svn revert`), reverse-merge, apply patch back